# IOS: Adding Overlay Image on UICollectionView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I'm using `UICollectionView` to generate a image gallery.I used `UIImage` inside the `UICollectionView` `Cell` to load the images. I need to select `UICollectionView` `Cell` by Long Press (not by single tap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick up the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate callback, grab the cell, and add an image as a subview.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCollectionViewCell *cell = (YourCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];//whichever frame you want it to appear at
    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];//set the image
    [cell.yourBaseImage addSubview:yourImageView];//or add it to whatever part of the cell you want
}
```

Or alternatively, just have a hidden imageView already setup inside of Storyboard. And then unhide it and set the image inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: No prob! All the best!

Comment: ,How can I remove that overlay image of a particular cell, using didDeselectItemAtIndexPath method? Thanks

Comment: Don't you think this messes up scrolling and cell reuse? what happens when the cell goes off screen and then comes back on? It's lost the state of whether or not it was selected. The proper way to do this is to change the state of the model object and let the cell pick it up from there.

Comment: What is "yourBaseImage" on the last line?